# Timestamp with time zone in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

encountered this error when copying data, which is just unloaded from one redshift table, into another redshift table

```
Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS]
```

the data entry is:

```
2016-07-07T14:17:57.360+02:00
```

How could I solve it?

Hard to image unload the data and can not load it back again on Redshift.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `TIMEFORMAT 'auto'` to your load parameters.

See the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/automatic-recognition.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the docs. That looks like it would solve the issue, but unfortunately it does not. See my answer below for a solution in another question.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue, and using `TIMEFORMAT 'auto'` did not solve it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757610/copy-a-datetime-with-the-format-rfc822-into-redshift/50914190#50914190) to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757610/copy-a-datetime-with-the-format-rfc822-into-redshift) explains a workaround using an intermediate table with a varchar field